# Entity Framework 4.1 code first with a DB2 Linked Server in SQL

Tags: db2, entity-framework-4.1, linked-server

I would like to use Entity Framework 4.1 Code-First to build connections to my databases whether they are on our SQL server or DB2.  I feel like I'm almost there, but just can't get it to work.

We're using SQL 2005 and have a Linked Server setup to our DB2 mainframe called ISERIES DATA.

Here's my entity object:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace HOP.Infrastructure.Model
{
    [Table("EDIHA101_DEMO")]
    public class EDIHA101
    {
        [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
        public int HABCH { get; set; }

        [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
        public int HABSQ { get; set; }

        public int HAVND { get; set; }
        public string HACUS { get; set; }
        public string HAPRD { get; set; }
        public string HADSC { get; set; }
        public string HAUOM { get; set; }
        public string HADCK { get; set; }
        public string HALDT { get; set; }
        public string HALTM { get; set; }
        public int HAQQY { get; set; }
        public int HACQY { get; set; }
        public int HAOQY { get; set; }
        public int HAPON { get; set; }
        public string HACMT { get; set; }
        public string HAADT { get; set; }
        public string HAATM { get; set; }
        public string HADTP { get; set; }
        public string HADID { get; set; }
        public int HAALN { get; set; }
        public int HAMDL { get; set; }
        public int HAAS1 { get; set; }
        public string HARDT { get; set; }
        public string HARTM { get; set; }
        public int HARQY { get; set; }
        public int HANQY { get; set; }
        public int HADBL { get; set; }
        public int HARSQ { get; set; }
        public int HAASN { get; set; }
        public int HABOL { get; set; }
        public string HADWG { get; set; }
        public string HAREV { get; set; }
        public string HACBY { get; set; }
        public string HACDT { get; set; }
        public string HACTM { get; set; }
        public string HAFDT { get; set; }
        public string HAFTM { get; set; }
        public string HACD1 { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The Table attribute on the class is pointing to a VIEW that I had created to expose the DB2 table. I can run SELECT queries against this view from SQL management studio and it returns data.

Here's the data context being used:

```
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace HOP.Infrastructure.Model
{
    public class EDIDataContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<EDIHA101> EDIHA101 { get; set; }

        public EDIDataContext(string connectionString) 
            : base(connectionString)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Here's the repository with the Create method that is trying to create a new record:

```
using HOP.Core.Interfaces;
using HOP.Infrastructure.Mappings;
using HOP.Infrastructure.Model;
using Domain = HOP.Core.Domain;
using Model  = HOP.Infrastructure.Model;

namespace HOP.Infrastructure.Repositories
{
    public class ItemRepository : IItemRepository
    {
        protected EDIDataContext db;

        public ItemRepository(EDIDataContext db)
        {
            this.db = db;
        }

        public void Create(Domain.Item item)
        {
            Model.EDIHA101 edi = item.Map();

            db.EDIHA101.Add(edi);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the connection string:

```
<add name="Development_AS400" connectionString="Data Source=SERVER_NAME;Initial Catalog=ISERIES DATA;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

When I execute the Create method in the repository code, I get this exception on the db.SaveChanges() line:

> "The requested operation could not be performed because OLE DB
>   provider \"DB2OLEDB\" for linked server \"ISERIES\" does not support
>   the required transaction interface."

I found this post that suggests turning on Journaling on DB2:

http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic265107-289-1.aspx

Our DB2 DBA does not want to enable Journaling, so can I disable transactions somehow in EF?  Or, is there something else I can try?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there any reason you can't connect to the server directly. The error you are receiving suggests an unsupported data provider  not journaling my only other suggestion I can think of is using replication instead of linked servers as am not 100% sure that linked servers / oledb or odac is directly supported out of the box in ef4.1 I know there are some 3rd party providers such as dot connect from devart that will support these however they do have an additional expense attached to them

Comment: In my experience un journaled databases only generate warnings and shouldn't cause these sort of errors as Ed is simp,y generating simple SQL statements

Comment: I can connect to the DB2 server directly, but it requires a driver to be loaded on the developer and servers. We've just experience a problem where updating that driver on a server is going to require us to update all applications using that driver. We'd rather use a linked server because all our development efforts would be using the same connection methods.

Comment: If EF 4.1 doesn't support DB2, would Linq To SQL be any better?

Comment: By connecting directly I mean - I can connect to DB2 using a .net provider to open a connection. I'm not sure if you meant connect directly using EF?

Comment: oledb and db2 connections arent supported out of the box. but it can be used with 3rd party drivers such as dotconnect but are an additional cost linq to sql only works with native sql server connections and is essentially deprecated and should be replaced with entity framework